# Is is possible to read in a list of numbers in SML?

Tags: input, io, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to make a program in SML that will read in a series/list/sequence of numbers from the user, process the numbers, and output the result. I don't know how many numbers the user will input. The program can either read in all the numbers and output the results all together or read and output one at a time. I don't care whether the input is in a separate file or manually input at a console.

What do I need to do to be able to read input?

```
fun fact x = if x<2 then 1 else x*fact(x-1); 

let val keepgoing:bool ref = ref true in
   while !keepgoing do
      let val num = valOf(TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn) in 
      print( Int.toString( fact( valOf( Int.fromString( num ) ) ) ) );
      keepgoing := (null(explode(num)))
   end
end;
```

Sorry about the convoluted conversions. If you also know an easier way to read in integers, I'd appreciate that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is just flawed here.  You want `keepgoing := not (null (explode num))`.  Right?  It works fine for me with that change.  You need to implement removal of the final newline (so null explode does what you want) and parsing a line with more than one number, but you basically have the right idea.

Comment: Thanks. This is more of an exercise, so it doesn't need to be especially robust. Your change is exactly what I was looking for. Sometimes the problem's just a simple error.